# Table centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Could someone please help me to center the equations in this table? This is the first table I'm making in LaTeX, and I can't find the right way to do it.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}||p{5cm}|p{5cm}|  }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Erdseilström} \\
    \hline
    &Einfachleitung &Doppelleitung\\[10pt]
    \hline
    1 Erdseil   & $I_N = -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0$  &  $I_N= -\frac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0$\\[20pt]
    2 Erdseile &   $I_{N_1} = I_{N_2}= -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0$   & $I_{N_1}=I_{N_2}=  -\frac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}}$ \\[20pt]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: p columns aren't centered

Comment: Since line-breaking inside cells wouldn't seem to be desirable, don't use a column type that allows automatic line-breaking.

Answer (score 6):

similar to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) solution. small differences is use `amsmath` for math writing and `makecell` for vertical line spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
{\noindent
 \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l >{$}c<{$} >{$}c<{$}}
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Erdseilström}            \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    &   \text{Einfachleitung}
        &   \text{Doppelleitung}                    \\
    \midrule
1 Erdseil
    &   I_N = -\dfrac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0
        &   I_N = -\dfrac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0      \\
2 Erdseile
    &   I_{N_{1,2}}= -\dfrac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0
        &   I_{N_{1,2}}= -\dfrac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}}
                                                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border).

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest that you use an `array` environment, since most of the cells employ math mode. Note that I don't use any vertical lines and fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}  % left-aligned text mode in an "array"
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} LCC @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$Erdseilström$} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-3}
    &$Einfachleitung$ &$Doppelleitung$\\
    \midrule
    1 Erdseil   & I_N = -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0  
                & I_N= -\frac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0\\
    \addlinespace
    2 Erdseile  & I_{N_1} = I_{N_2}= -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0 
                & I_{N_1}=I_{N_2}=  -\frac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question. If the table must span the full width of the textblock, I'd suggest using a `tabular*` environment, with its full width set to `\textwidth`. (The `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` bit instructs LaTeX to insert as much intercolumn whitespace as is needed to fill up the target width. The `array` and `tabular` environments aren't set up to take a target width as one of their main parameters.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begingroup  % localize scope of the next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} CC } 
\toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Erdseilström} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-3} 
&$Einfachleitung$ &$Doppelleitung$\\ 
\midrule 
1 Erdseil  & I_N = -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0 
           & I_N = -\frac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0\\ 
\addlinespace 
2 Erdseile & I_{N_{1,2}}= -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0 
           & I_{N_{1,2}}= -\frac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Same idea with a little arraystretch for lisibility.

Comment: Tnx @Mico, I just changed equations a bit (they are shorter), so how can I strech the table from margin to margin?  Here how it looks now:\[
\begin{array}{@{} LCC @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{$Erdseilström$} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
&$Einfachleitung$ &$Doppelleitung$\\
\midrule
1 Erdseil   & I_N = -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0  
& I_N= -\frac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0\\
\addlinespace
2 Erdseile  & I_{N_{1,2}}= -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0 
& I_{N_{1,2}}=  -\frac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]

Comment: @elsol, please edit your question and put changes there that will be visible to all

Answer (score 4):

Mico's layout is more professional and is to be preferred, but if you want to keep yours:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}||C{5cm}|C{5cm}|  }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Erdseilström} \\[10pt]
    \hline
    &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Einfachleitung} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Doppelleitung}\\[10pt]
    \hline
    1 Erdseil   & I_N = -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0  & I_N= -\frac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0\\[20pt]
    2 Erdseile &  I_{N_1} = I_{N_2}= -\frac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0   & I_{N_1}=I_{N_2}=  -\frac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} \\[20pt]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple possibility, with the `array` package. I added some improvements  as to the vertical spacing, with the `cellspace` package, which ensures a minimal padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier preffixed withe letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). Also, I used the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`, and `hhline` for the intersection of double lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % provides medium sized formulae and acontrol of intertext spacing via an optional argument

\usepackage{cellspace, hhline}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

    \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}||S{>{\centering\arraybackslash} p{5cm}}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}| }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|Sc|}{Erdseilström} \\
    \hline
    &Einfachleitung &Doppelleitung\\
    \hhline{-||--}
    1 Erdseil & $I_N = -\mfrac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0$ & $I_N= -\mfrac{6Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}} I_0$\\
    2 Erdseile & $I_{N_1} = I_{N_2}= -\mfrac{3Z_{NX}}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}} I_0$ & $I_{N_1}=I_{N_2}= -\mfrac{3I_{0}(Z_{NX}+Z_{NY})}{Z_{NN}+Z_{N_1N_2}}$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]